# problemas con agregar un campo con modal en array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, select2

tengo un array funcionando, pero al darle clic en el boton gregar input dentro del array solo me agrega el valor con una ventana modal al primer input y pero no fuciona con el resto de filas del array. 
envio el codigo actual:

Comment: Explica un poco mejor, ¿te refieres que en vez de crear el select2 en tu archivo html hacerlo desde un archivo aparte .js?

Comment: hola, lo que sucede es que tengo un archivo php que es donde funciona mi select2 y no hay problemas pero ahora tengo un array en un .js y necesito agregar el select2 ahi , pero no se como hacer para cargar las librerias que se necesitan para que el select funcione dentro del .js, ya que las tengo en el php me muestro  en pantalla.

Comment: La cosa que quieres hacer se me hace extraña, pero seguire preguntando para poder ayudarte,  ¿porque mencionas el array? ¿quieres que el select muestre los valores del array?

Comment: ya tengo el array listo, solo necesito poder crear un select2 dentro del .js , pero no se como cargar las librerias de la misma para que me funcione tal cual como en el php, en otras palabras lo que necesito es un ejemplo de un select2  pero funcionando desde un .js

Comment: Amiga creo que estas confundida, dentro de los archivos js no puedes agregar librerías, lo que debes es agregarlos antes de que agregues la referencia de tu archivo js donde tienes el array, esto lo haces en el archivo de tu pagina donde pones el codigo Html.

Comment: Es decir que el orden en que tienes las referencias de tus `Scripts` esta bien y puedes usar libremente cualquier código de tu `Select2` o cualquier librería que hayas agregado antes.

Comment: tienes algun ejemplo, he intentado varias formas para llamar las librerias en el js para que me funcione el select2  ya que lo tengo creado en el .js y pues no funciona por que faltan las librerias que tengo en el php .

Comment: `<script src="select2.min.js"></script> <script src="es.js"></script>` eso lo tienes en el codigo que pusiste en la pregunta, como ves tienes la referencia a `Select2` antes que a tu script `es.js` eso significa que cualquier codigo de `Select2` lo puedes usar en tu archivo `es.js` que es archivo donde supongo que tienes el array.

Comment: ¿Pero que quieres hacer dentro de tu archivo js?

Comment: tal cual pero en mi archivo es.js llamo el select tal cual como lo cree en el php pero no me carga es como si no estuviera reconociendo las librerias.

Comment: 1-¿A que te refieres con que no te carga? 2-¿Te da algún error? 3-¿quieres crear un select2 desde tu archivo externo?

Comment: el select que cree en el archivo externo .js no me carga, muestra como si las librerias no estuvieran.

Comment: ¿Es decir tu select2 no se crea se queda como un select normal?

Comment: si, y no me carga como el select del php

Comment: Pues edita la pregunta pon el código del archivo js y el codigo html donde esta el select2 y te ayudaremos

Comment: vale , ya la edito

Comment: ya edite la pregunta, es mas especifica donde el archivo select2.js que esta al final del archivo.php me deberia cargar el segundo select que me lo muestra en el mismo archivo.php donde dice centro de costos pero no carga.

Comment: Quieres que este select: `<select class='categoryName form-control' style='width:200px' name='categoryName'></select> ` que creas dentro de tu ciclo tome el estilo de un `Select2`?

Comment: lo que necesito es que ese select funcione como el primero

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregándole a tu select en el HTML, la clase `class="js-state select2"`, simplemente se lo añades a las que tiene ya dicho elemento, de tal manera que te pueda quedar algo como:

```
class="categoryName form-control js-state select2"
```

O también puedes cargarle el método a dihco elemento al momento de cargar la página en el mismo javascript, es decír algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".categoryName").select2();
})
```

Comment: el problema no es para crear el select si no es para cargar las librerias de "script" dentro del .js del select que senecesita para que el select funcione, ya que lo que necesito es pasar el select2 que tengo actualmente a un archivo .js

Comment: Si tienes problemas para cargar la librería, ya te aseguraste de tenerla en un archivo?.. yo te recomiendo la minificada, para incluir la librería es simplemente añadir el script:
`<script src="...public/select2/js/select2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: las librerias del select las tengo en el php y funciona sin problemas con el primer select.

Answer (score 0):

Estas creando un select2 con tu etiqueta `script` cuando carga la pagina solamente, esto significa que si creas otro select con tu codigo( como lo haces en tu ciclo `for`) no le afectara el codigo de convertirlo a **select2** por lo que deberias ejecutar ese codigo cada vez que agregues un *select* nuevo.

La solución sencilla seria:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.fn.select2.defaults.set('language', 'es'); 
function select(){
  $('.categoryName').select2({   
    placeholder: 'Selecciona una categoría', 
    ajax: { 
      url: 'conexion.php',       
      dataType: 'json',         
      delay: 250,        
     data: function (params) { 
       return { q: params.term }; 
     }, 
     processResults: function (data) { 
       return { results: data }; 
      }, 
      cache: true   
    }        
  });
}
select();//llamamos la funcion creada para que funcione una vez se cargue la pagina      
</script>
```

Esos son los cambios en tu etiqueta `script` ahora lo unico que tenemos que hacer desde tu archivo *js* es llamar la función una vez crees el otro select en tu ciclo `for`.

```
  totalFinal = detalles[i].moneda+" "+total;
}
select();//volvemos a llamar la función creada en la etiqueta script al final de toda la función..
```

Como ves luego de que termines de tu logica en tu archivo *js* donde has agregado tu nuevo *select* al final vuelves a llamar a la función para que esta se encargue de convertir el nuevo select en un **Select2** como el otro.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo mínimo pero que creo que es la solución que buscas:
*archivo externo .js*

```js
function add(select){
    $("#container").append(select);//agregamos el nuevo select a la pagina
}
$("#button").click(function (e) { 
    var  select = '<select class="mySelect"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>';
    add(select);//llamamos a la anterior funcion y le pasamos el diseño de nuestro select
    selectConvert();//luego de agregado el select llamamos a la funcion selectConvert() para actualizar el select
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Select2</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-4">

        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-4" id="container">
            <select class="mySelect">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-info" id="button">agregar select</button>
        </div>

    </div>
        <script>
        function selectConvert(){
            $(".mySelect").select2();
        }
        selectConvert();

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*en la pagina principal ↑*

Como ves con ese codigo soy capaz de agregar selects por codigo y convertilo a Select2 llamando la funcion **selectConvert()** cada vez que agregue uno.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88592/discussion-on-answer-by-denifer-santiago-fernandez-problemas-con-agregar-un-camp).

Comment: Gracias, no lo había hecho debido a que ella no tiene suficientes puntos para entrar